# Automatically parse selectors with insheetjson in Stata

Tags: json, api, stata

I am trying to build a program that gets data from Statistics Denmark's API using insheetjson in Stata. However, I have not been able to find a solution for the following problem: I want to get the metadata from a random table (in this case: "FOLK1A" which is a table of demographics). This table has variables of region, age, marital status and time. If we take regions as an example, there are 105 regions, so if I run `insheetjson using "https://api.statbank.dk/v1/tableinfo/FOLK1A?lang=en", showresponse flatten`, I see a very clear pattern:

```
        variables:1:values:1:id = 000
        variables:1:values:1:text = All Denmark
        variables:1:values:2:id = 084
        variables:1:values:2:text = Region Hovedstaden
        variables:1:values:3:id = 101
        variables:1:values:3:text = Copenhagen
        variables:1:values:4:id = 147
        variables:1:values:4:text = Frederiksberg
        variables:1:values:5:id = 155
        variables:1:values:5:text = Dragør
        variables:1:values:6:id = 185
        variables:1:values:6:text = Tårnby
        variables:1:values:7:id = 165
        variables:1:values:7:text = Albertslund
        variables:1:values:8:id = 151
        variables:1:values:8:text = Ballerup
        variables:1:values:9:id = 153
        variables:1:values:9:text = Brøndby
        variables:1:values:10:id = 157
        variables:1:values:10:text = Gentofte
...
        variables:1:values:100:text = Mariagerfjord
        variables:1:values:101:id = 773
        variables:1:values:101:text = Morsø
        variables:1:values:102:id = 840
        variables:1:values:102:text = Rebild
        variables:1:values:103:id = 787
        variables:1:values:103:text = Thisted
        variables:1:values:104:id = 820
        variables:1:values:104:text = Vesthimmerlands
        variables:1:values:105:id = 851
        variables:1:values:105:text = Aalborg
```

However, I am not able not parse all these regions in a single call. Is there a way to tell insheetjson to get all of these regions, i.e. "variables:1:values:[1-105]:id" in one call? I don't want to run the command several times, thus pinging the server way too much.

Best regards,
Emil Blicher

Comment: Cross-posted at https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1641288-automatically-parse-selectors-with-insheetjson

Comment: Well nobody answered so I thought that I might as well try another place.

Comment: That’s understandable. The point is just to tell each forum.

Comment: I think the lack of answers on either forum stems from an unclear objective. Is it simply that you want to store the regions and their region code as variables?

Comment: Yes! It seems very simple but I have not been able to do it in a single call. I could theoretically do it using - in this case - 105 calls, but that would obviously not be a good way.